# AngularJS : variable of ng-repeat loop not updating $scope fast enough

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an item tree in $scope on which I want to iterate with ng-repeat and include a different template according to node type. The tree is something like

```
$scope.item = {
  ID: 1,
  children: {
    1: {
      ID: 11,
      },
    2: {
      ID: 12,
    }
  },
};
```

The problem is that when I do something like

```
<div ng-repeat="item in item.children">
  item.ID : {{item.ID}}
  <div ng-include="showVars(item.ID)"></div>
</div>
```

the argument of the showVars function is the item.ID value as evaluated in the parent scope, not the subscope created by ng-repeat. When displayed with `{{item.ID}}`, the value is correct though.

Example in [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XhTD9/2/).

My understanding is that the value in the subscope is not updated yet when I call the function, am I right? Is this AngularJS' normal behaviour or a bug?

Edit:

To make it more explicit, in the Fiddle I expect

```
calling getTemplate with $scope.item.ID = 12 and itemID = 12
```

instead of

```
calling getTemplate with $scope.item.ID = 1  and itemID = 12
```

because ng-repeat is supposed to assign $scope.item with the variable.

Thank you,

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. all the logs show that the correct item ID is received by the method: "and itemID = 12". And the included template also displays the child ID: "My Template with item.ID = 12".

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit : the problem is, as you can see in the log, that, when ng-include is evaluated, $scope.item is still the same as in parent scope, while I would expect it to be the $scope.item of child scope created by ng-repeat.

To make it even more explicit, I would expect
`calling getTemplate with $scope.item.ID = 12 and itemID = 12`
instead of 
`calling getTemplate with $scope.item.ID = 1 and itemID = 12`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behavior.

When you created the controller's `showVars` function, you are closing over `$scope`, which is the scope of the parent controller.  So when you reference `$scope`, you are getting that scope that was injected into the controller.

In other words, `$scope` doesn't change based on the execution of the function.  This is why you want to pass the item into the function as a parameter.

If you want access to the child scope in the function, you can do this using `this`:

```
this.item.ID
```

Here is a working [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3NH8V/)

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a great help to me! I globally understand now, especially with the help of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers#answer-14168699) and [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures).

Comment: Thanks, @ElieRoux.  If you like my answer, please mark it as the correct answer.